# Is it possible to make an Alarm App with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, alarm

Im relatively new to programming and have been learning for the past three months. Im currently working on developing an alarm app using Expo. However Im unsure about Expos technical capabilities for achieving the following functionality:

Running the app in the background: Is it possible to keep the alarm app running in the background even when the device is locked or another app is active?

Starting music playback at a specific time: Can Expo handle scheduling events to start playing music at a predefined time, even if the app is not currently in the foreground?

I have gone through the Expo documentation but as a beginner, my understanding is limited, and I couldn't find a clear solution for running an alarm app in the background with scheduled music playback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create it with the expo. But it is best to install Yarn or Cli.